# How can I convert a string into a date object and get year, month and day separately?

Tags: python, string, datetime

If I have lets say this string "2008-12-12 19:21:10" how can I convert it into a date and get the year, month and day from that created object separately?

Comment: I forgot to say I would like to get something like:
object.getYear() #will print the string'2008' or something like that

Comment: You could easily create a class the used `datetime` or contained a `datetime.datetime` instance and provided a `get_year()` method.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Now you have a `datetime.datetime` object, and it has [`.year`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year), [`.month`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.month) and [`.day`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day) attributes:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datestring = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print dt.year, dt.month, dt.day
2008 12 12
```

Answer (score 7):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm
Here you can find strptime() method complete description. where you can find all type of strings.
Eg:- To convert string like this '15-MAY-12'

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>datestring = "15-MAY-12"
>>>dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%d-%b-%Y')
>>>print(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
 2012 MAY 15
```

Comment: This code gives an error; you have to change the Y to y. As the answer below notes, '%y is for two digit year notation %Y is for the four digit one'.

Answer (score 5):

with **milliseconds**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datestring = "2018-04-11 23:36:18.886585"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> print dt.year, dt.month, dt.day
2018 04 11
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing to add; pay attention that `%y` is for two digit year notation `%Y` is for the four digit one:

```
import datetime

datestring = '15-MAY-12'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%d-%b-%y'))
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 15, 0, 0)

datestring = '15-MAY-2012'    
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%d-%b-%Y'))
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 15, 0, 0)
```