# what is the index of second "/" in 12/25/2009?

Tags: python

`what is the index of the second "/" in a date.

```
  date = input('write todays date: ')
  i  = date.find('/')

  month = date\[:i]
  day =??????
  year = ???????
  print(f' todays month is {month}')
```

I tried all my knowledge did not work`

Comment: I recommend using a proper date library rather than handling the parsing yourself.  e.g. you could use `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: I agree with @0x5453. I you want to know how to work with strings you can also do : `month, day, year = date.split("/")`

Otherwise, to answer directly to your question the index of the second "/" si 5

Comment: you could also use `date.split('/')` which will give you a list and you just index into the elements that you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the nth occurrence of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string) Also see [How can I convert a string into a date object and get year, month and day separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430287/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-date-object-and-get-year-month-and-day-separa)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use `datetime` to perform parsing and formatting, in this case using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime('12/25/2009', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 25, 0, 0)
>>> dt.month, dt.day, dt.year
(12, 25, 2009)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python method `find` takes optional arguments. You can pass the start index to look for. In your case the start would be the end index of the first match.

Example:

```
first = date_str.find("/")
if (first == -1):
     # not found
second = date_str.find("/", first + 1)
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the second "/" in that date format would be index 2 if you were looking at that string as a zero based array.

So I say... ***2***

Comment: the 2nd index of the string "12/25/2009" is indeed "/" but it is the first "/" the second is of index 5.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is asking for a way to find this programmatically for any string.

Comment: I understand now, apologies for my bad answer.